# A Dedekind Finite Non-Regular Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

An element $r$ in a ring $R$ is called a regular element if there exists $s \in R$ such that $rsr=r$. The ring $R$ is called *regular* if all its elements are regular.

> Is there any Dedekind Finite ring which is not regular?

Edit: A ring $R$ is called *Dedekind Finite* if for any $a,b \in R$, $ab=1$ implies $ba=1$.

Comment: Any commutative non-Noetherian ring will be Dedekind finite yet not regular.

Comment: What is the definition of "Dedekind finite ring"?

Comment: A commutative ring is regular iff it has no nilpotent elements and its Krull dimension is zero. This gives tons of examples.

Comment: (Noetherianity has not much to do with this, no?)

Comment: Is 2 a regular element in that ring?

Answer (score 1):

Examples:

Any commutative ring which isn't regular.

Any right (or left) Noetherian ring which isn't regular.

Any domain (ring without nonzero zero divisors) which isn't a field.

Any connected ring (a ring with only trivial idempotents) that isn't a field. This includes both local rings and domains.